# Inputting math symbols in Android

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I need to input calculus and trigonometric notations in Android.

How to input math symbols in Android?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the answer might help if there are still people looking for what the OP asked.
There is [MathKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agp.mathkeyboard) that comes loaded with math symbols from trigonometric symbols to logarithmic, integrals, subscripts, superscripts, etc.

> From square roots to triple integrals, this keyboard helps you in math typing
>
> MathKeyboard it's a keyboard that helps you with symbolic typing, for the ones who struggle to get a decent math text in common apps, this keyboard is fully compatible with all instant message services

When you open the keyboard, click on Menu to select symbols' categories.

The only caveat is that the free version contains ads.

Answer (score 1):

Some replacement Android keyboards on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=math%20keyboard&c=apps) deal with mathematical characters (I don't need many, so my keyboard is sufficient), and some mathematical apps provide a very broad range. See this Google Play [query](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=calculus&c=apps) to see if any are a match to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with your existing gboard.
Go to
Settings>language & input>gboard settings>languages>add Greek>save
Hope this helps.